# advice on grounding lamp and ballast required

Tags: wiring

Greetings to DIY community,

That's my first DIY experience, and I literally have zero experience with electricity. I would appreciate any advice if I am missing or doing something wrong here.

I am trying to wire a [Philips TUV 55W PLL lamp](https://www.assets.signify.com/is/content/PhilipsLighting/fp927908704007-pss-en_us) with a [WH43-UNV-L ballast](https://www.fulham.com/PDFs/SpecSheets/WH43-UNV-L-2014-467.pdf) according to the [Fulham datasheet](https://www.fulham.com/PDFs/SunHorse-UV-Flyer.pdf) (diagram. 12). I know that this ballast is discontinued for now, but at least I managed to get it at this time.
In addition, I know that this lamp type expects programmed start instead of instant start one.

The documentation states "This ballast case must be grounded".

Let's say I am going to use this type of [cord](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BQ8PY21), would attaching "green" wire to the ballast's box would be enough to be "grounded"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the cord attaches to the fixture or to a multiwire splice that connects to the housing and to the ballast if the ballast has a grounding wire or terminal. If the ballast doesn't have a ground wire or terminal the ballast is just grounded to the fixture housing by it's mounting screws.

The ground wire on the cord usually attaches to a designated (green) screw on the fixture frame. If the ballast has no direct ground connection then you can use a blue (for #14 and #16 wire) stake-on fork on the stranded wire from the cord and attach it directly under the ground screw or you can wrap a short piece of solid green or bare #14 wire around the screw and attach it to the cord by a wire connector.

If the ballast has a ground terminal or wire that connection is not adequate to ground the whole fixture by that ground connection. Normally you would connect a short piece of bare or green #12 or #14 wire to the fixture ground screw, then use a wire connector it to the ground wire on the cord and the wire grounding to the ballast.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, it is really helpful. 

May I ask you to take a look to the next question as well?
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189529/wire-connection-between-ballast-and-lamp-socket