# Wire connection between ballast and lamp socket

Tags: wiring

I want to connect wires from ballast [WH43-UNV-L](https://www.fulham.com/PDFs/SpecSheets/WH43-UNV-L-2014-467.pdf) to socket 2g11 ([1100-VS VERTICAL SNAP-IN OR TWO HOLE MOUNT](https://egaynor.com/product/1100-vs-vertical-snap-in-or-two-hole-mount/)).

Here is the fulham connection diagram for my type of ballast and my type of lamp:

[image]

My ballast have 4 red and 1 yellow wires.

Would it be OK if I connect wires according to the following picture?

[image]

**UPD1:**

If I understand right about "siamesed" holes, connection should look like below.
Red wires should be joined before inserting into the last available hole.

[image]

Appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Are these shunting or non-shunting lampholders?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, that strange feeling, when after reading the question, you understand that you've learned something new... I don't know. Even if I would have a multimeter, don't know how to test it, because holes is too small ... Any advice?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, find out - it is shunted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  **You need to wire the lamps according to the diagram**.  What you propose does not match the diagram.

On the yellow, the diagram says you must split the yellow wire to power both filament terminals on one "end" of the bulb.

On the red, you must join 3 wires then split them to power both filament terminals on the other end.

This splitting will take extra wires and wire-nuts. Use #18 solid wire rated 600V.  If you have spare length of ballast wire, you can use a little bit of that.

This particular lampholder seems to have 3 holes per "side".  Note that 2 of those holes are "siamesed".  That is telling you they are interconnected to each other/ the same thing. Only connect to one of them.

Comment: Added UPD1 section. Take a look please.
Thank you for your explanation, that's extremely helpful ...

Comment: @Eugene yes, that looks right to me.  Double check with a voltmeter for continuity to the socket terminals.