# Ballast + lamp. Putting all together

Tags: wiring, ballast

I would like to thank community for helping me with my initial questions regarding this project [part I](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189259/advice-on-grounding-lamp-and-ballast-required) and [part II](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189529/wire-connection-between-ballast-and-lamp-socket).

Finally, I put all the parts together and would like you to review it before I plug it in.

Here are the component parts:

- [Bergen Industries Inc PS915143 3-Wire Appliance and Power Tool Cord](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BQ8PY21)
- [Fulham WH43-UNV-L](https://www.fulham.com/PDFs/SpecSheets/WH43-UNV-L-2014-467.pdf)
- [TUV 55W PLL](https://www.assets.signify.com/is/content/PhilipsLighting/fp927908704007-pss-en_us)
- [Shunted socket](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2G11-Lampholder-Vertical-Snap-In-4-Pin-CFL-Compact-Fluorescent-Socket-26113/271257612186?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649)

Here is the schema I wanted to use between ballast and socket:

[image]

And here are the photos of all other parts:

[image][image][image][image]

In future I would cover the ballast and wires by some plastic box just for safety reasons.

Few questions below:

**Common:**

I have a Philips 55W twin tube lamp (Philips recommends ballast with programmed start type).

My current ballast WH-43 has instant start type.
From fulham’s documentation it is OK to use this type of ballast with Philips 55W lamp.
I read that using instant start type only affects lamp's lifetime.

- But the question is: does it have any other side effects? (safety or any other)

**Working mode:**

- How dangerous it might be to touch the ballast while it is plugged in?
  (I am not going to touch it anyway, under no circumstances. Just out of curiosity)
- Is that safe to plug it in without lamp in the socket?

**Connection & wires:**

- Is ground wire connected properly?

**Safety concerns:**

- How safe would be wood base in normal mode?
- How safe would be wood base during short circuit? (Is that possible that the base would catch a fire)?
- What is the proper material for base in such a project?

Any other advice?

Thank you.

**UPD:**

Thank you all for your help!

Final result, click to enlarge.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earth connection should be a ring terminal under the screw.
With the earth connection it will be safe to touch the ballast case in all circumstances

Dry wood does not conduct electricity, nor does it pose a fire threat due to electrical faults

I'm not a big fan of those pliers crimp connectors. (but that's personal opinion)

The ballast will be safe and come to no harm with no lamp connected.

Some sort of strain-relief clamp should be arranged on the jacket of the appliance cord
so that yanking the cable does not disturb the connections.

I would not expect the ballast to get hot get hot enough to start a fire

Comment: Crimp-type terminals work *much better* if you use a ratchet-type (vs a pliers-type) crimp tool to crimp them

Comment: Just curious, how would you attach a ring terminal without a crimp since you do not care for them? Solder only is a no no on this side of the pond.